# What should I do about a flurry of verification codes from Yahoo?

Tags: security, yahoo

I have received a flurry of text messages and a phone call from Yahoo, with a series of verification codes. As I am not currently trying to access their services, is this something that requires action, like informing someone at Yahoo?

Comment: It is either a bug in their system or somebody is trying to access your account. If you don't have a Yahoo account with 2-factor authentication enabled, you can either block the number, or contact Yahoo to have them your number from the given account.  If you do have an Yahoo account with 2-factor authentication enabled.  You can either ignore it knowing you are safe, or change your password on a known virus free device, then contact Yahoo for support.

Comment: @Ramhound: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @AlE. - I don't post answers based on what I believe is the answer.  Unless I get some sort of additional information, I won't be submitting an answer, and more then likely just delete the comment to avoid additional pings.